# Error when calling Google Speech API on certain audio clips

Tags: python, firebase, google-api, firebase-storage, google-speech-api

I've been tearing my hair out over this one: For some audio clips I have no trouble at all passing them to the google speech api, and having them turned into transcripts, but for others I repeatedly get this cryptic error message:

```
RetryError: GaxError(Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED, The caller does not have permission)>)
```

This was the Python code I ran which generated the error. For some inputs to `source_uri` it works fine, but for others it repeatedly produced the above error, despite that fact that both the uri's which work and the uri's which fail are in the same firebase project, with the same permissions:

```
from google.cloud import speech

speech_client = speech.Client()
audio_sample = speech_client.sample(content=None,source_uri='gs://path/to/firebase/audio.wav',encoding='LINEAR16',sample_rate_hertz=16000)
operation = audio_sample.long_running_recognize('en-US')
```

And yes, I did run `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/credentials.json` beforehand.

I found a few other people encountering a similar issue [here](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-ruby/issues/40) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/697).

EDIT: After some further poking around, I've noticed that the errors exclusively happen on audio files uploaded after some cutoff point between 4/10/17-4/19/17, despite the fact that no firebase permissions where changed during this time.